# Remove string data between double quotes to de-identify data/remove PHI in Notepad++

Tags: pipe, notepad++

How can I remove string data between double quotes in a Pipe Delimited file?  Would like to maintain file structure and could replace the string data with "NULL" or a space? File can have multiple rows with 150 + columns with Alpha/numeric data between "".

```
Sample Data (one row):"900085322P"|"Fred Flinstone"|"GUMBY"|" "|"83562315"|"00010101"|"M"|"FRED"|"9999999999"|"Address1"|" "|"city"|"state"|"zip"|"US"|"street"|" "|"city"|"State"|"Zipcode"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"021"|"Y"|"Y"|"FILLER"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"1538637137"|"003"|"20200601"|"20200630"|" "|"Address1"|" "|"City"|"State"|"Zip"|""
```

Expected output:

```
""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"",etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you data, there are no escaped double quotes, so you might use a pattern that matches between the double quotes, but should also not match a pipe char:

```
"\K[^"|]+(?=")
```

**Explanation**

- `"` Match a double quote
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^"|]*` match 1+ chars except a double quote or pipe
- `(?=")` Assert a double quote to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xBbmJ/1).

[image]

If there can be escaped double quotes:

```
"\K[^"|\\]*(?:\\.[^"|\\]*)*(?=")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rTTx7t/1)

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for what what I intended to use it for!  Much Appreciated!